# How to cache an array using IDistributedCache?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, caching, .net-6.0

I have a project that is written in C# on the top of ASP.NET Core 6 framework.

I need to cache data of type `AppraisalResult[]` using `IDistributedCache`.

I created the following class:

```
public class AppraisalCacheService : IAppraisalCacheService
{
    private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;
    private readonly JsonSerializer _serializer;

    public AppraisalCacheService(IDistributedCache distributedCache)
    {
        _distributedCache = distributedCache;
        _serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    }

    public async Task<AppraisalResult[]> GetAsync(....)
    {
        // logic removed for simplicity
        var key = GetKey(..);
        var data = await _distributedCache.GetAsync(key);

        if (data != null)
        {
            using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            using BsonDataReader reader = new BsonDataReader(ms);

            return _serializer.Deserialize<AppraisalResult[]>(reader);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public async Task RemoveAsync(....)
    {
        // logic removed for simplicity
        var key = GetKey(..);

        await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(key);
    }

    public async Task StoreAsync(AppraisalResult[] results, ....)
    {
        // logic removed for simplicity
        var key = GetKey(..);

        using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using BsonDataWriter writer = new BsonDataWriter(ms);

        _serializer.Serialize(writer, results);

        await _distributedCache.SetAsync(key, ms.ToArray(), new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
        {
            SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7),
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
        });
    }

    private string GetKey(...)
    {
        // logic removed for simplicity
       return "custom-key....";
    }
}
```

The `StoreAsync()` method seems to be working fine. But, when I try to cast the cached value back into `AppraisalResult[]` it fails with the following error

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'AppraisalResult[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath '0'."}

**UPDATED**

When trying to ready from the cache prior deserializeing I am getting an error. Here is the code that I tried

```
var data = await _distributedCache.GetAsync(key);

if (data != null)
{
    using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
    using BsonDataReader reader = new BsonDataReader(ms);
    var dd = reader.ReadAsBytes(); 
}
```

The line `reader.ReadAsBytes()` throw the following exception before I deserialize:

> {"Error reading bytes. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '0'."}

Comment: You have done some minimal debugging right? LIke looking what you got in the MemoryStream before and after using the cache? What have you seen? What is the difference on that level?

Comment: @Ralf yes the error seems to be coming from reading the `BsonDataReader`. If I do `var dd = reader.ReadAsBytes();` before I deserilize, the get `{"Error reading bytes. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '0'."}` error

Comment: it looks like an error related with the data format. the expected data should be a Json object which like `{"property":[xxx]}` -> Json list but you gave a data like `[xxx]` -> list.

Comment: You have checked that data isn't null (nothing for this key exists)?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this is a limitation in Bson. You can't deserilize directly yo array object. The workaround was to create an object that contains the array property

```
public class AppraisalResultObj
{
    public AppraisalResult[] Results { get; set; }
}

public class AppraisalCacheService : IAppraisalCacheService
{
    private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;
    private readonly JsonSerializer _serializer;

    public AppraisalCacheService(IDistributedCache distributedCache)
    {
        _distributedCache = distributedCache;
        _serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    }

    public async Task<AppraisalResult[]> GetAsync(....)
    {
        // logic removed for simplicity
        var key = GetKey(..);
        var data = await _distributedCache.GetAsync(key);

        if (data != null)
        {
            using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            using BsonDataReader reader = new BsonDataReader(ms);

            var obj = _serializer.Deserialize<AppraisalResultObj>(reader);

            return obj.Results;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public async Task RemoveAsync(....)
    {
        // logic removed for simplicity
        var key = GetKey(..);

        await _distributedCache.RemoveAsync(key);
    }

    public async Task StoreAsync(AppraisalResult[] results, ....)
    {
        // logic removed for simplicity
        var key = GetKey(..);

        using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using BsonDataWriter writer = new BsonDataWriter(ms);

        _serializer.Serialize(writer, new AppraisalResultObj(){
            Results = results
         });

        await _distributedCache.SetAsync(key, ms.ToArray(), new DistributedCacheEntryOptions()
        {
            SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(7),
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
        });
    }

    private string GetKey(...)
    {
        // logic removed for simplicity
       return "custom-key....";
    }
}
```

then the code